# Log in vs. login

Tags: word-choice

From [Meta Stack Exchange log in page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dlogin&cdl=1):

> Completing log in to Area 51
>
> You will be redirected automatically

Shouldn't "log in" be spelled as "login"? I thought so but a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383932/log-in-should-be-login?noredirect=1#comment1280596_383932) said "log in" is ok in that context, so I am confused. I thought one should use "login" since it's a noun in that context.

Comment: Asked already.  Is it *login to, log into, or log in to*?  I believe the best answer was **log in to**.  When you think about it, that's the one that makes sense. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267327/do-i-log-into-login-to-or-log-in-to

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther in my question, I doubt it's used as a verb.

Answer (score 9):

The word "login/log in" used as a countable noun is relatively new to English. Since it's a technical term, rather than an everyday term, the English speaking community at large hasn't settled on a spelling yet, but the convention is certainly leaning strongly towards "login".

Stack Exchange should probably change the spelling there.

Ngrams of "[log in/login successful](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=log%20in%20successful%2Clogin%20successful&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)", "[log in/login was successful](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=log%20in%20was%20successful%2Clogin%20was%20successful&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)" and "[log in/login failed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=log%20in%20failed%2Clogin%20failed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)" all show no usage of "log in" as a noun.

Comment: Wouldn't you log in using a login?

Comment: "Login" is definitely a noun, and "log in" is definitely a verb. You can have 3 logins, but you can't have 3 log ins (or 3 logs in?). Likewise you can be logging in, or have logged in, but you can't be loginning or have loginned. But lots of verbs can also be used as a noun, especially in this sort of 'computer speak'. Try "Completing run", "Completing jump", "Completing wash", "Completing send", "Completing bite", etc. I had to get to *"Completing teach" before I found an example my brain really didn't like, to convince me it really ought to be a noun there.

Comment: @Ben "Completing send" and "completing wash" feel weird. They way I see it, in the other examples, the words are nouns - in the sense seen in, say, "I went for a run", "I took a bite", "it took two jumps before I reached it" - a single instance of running, biting, jumping, etc. Applying it to "run" as in running commands or "jump"  as in using a jump server didn't really change that.

Comment: @muru Yes, and I suspect everyone has slightly different feelings about which verbs can be used as nouns like that. We'll all mostly agree on the common ones, less so on the rare examples. But it means answering this question doesn't *just* depend on the "login" vs "log in" noun/verb distinction, but also on whether the "log in" verb can be used as a noun in that way. To me it read okay, because I think of "login" as primarily meaning a set of credentials and only very weakly meaning the general procedure of logging in, so using "log in" as short for "log in procedure" is a bit more natural.

Comment: @muru But if I was going to write that message myself, I would use "Logging in to Area 51" in preference to either "Completing login ..." or "Completing log in ..."

Comment: @muru: I would call that the "login details", whereas the login is the act of logging in. In order words, you **log in** using your **login details**, and if you provided the correct information your **login** will succeed. That being said, I have heard others use "login" in the sense of "user credentials" (which is what you mean in your comment), but not very often and I'm not a fan of it in general.

Answer (score 4):

I'd tend to agree with you Frank.  Generally the process of logging in is called "a login".  There is variation.  The compound noun "log-in" is sometimes seen and an "open compound"  ie 'log in' seems within the range of acceptable variation.

So you might consider this a mistake, but it is a pretty minor one. It doesn't affect understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Many words have different forms as verbs and nouns. Verbs are typically separate words. As nouns, the same words are often combined (or hyphenated as a compound adjective). This can be a matter of style -- some style guides will specify whether specific words and phrases are spelled as one or two words. Here are some common examples of different spellings for verbs vs. nouns:

*You should log in using your login name.*

*Please stand up for the standup meeting at 9 a.m.*

*I like a closet I can walk in to, so I'm glad the bedroom has a walkin closet.*

*Please sign up by putting your name on the signup sheet.*

Comment: This should really have more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

"Login" is a noun. It can refer to credentials (short for login username + login password) or location or phase in which the act will be performed (short for login screen or login process). But importantly, **it's not a verb** -- you don't "login" to something, although your "login" (the phase/process) can be successful or fail.

"Log in" alone refers to the action of inputting+submitting credentials, and is a verb that can be used as a noun (Completing log in).

"Completing login" has a somewhat different meaning, in that it refers to the whole process undergoing completion rather than the specific input action part of it. This won't be obvious to non-programmers, but the literal "log in" portion of entering+submitting credentials is only one part of a "login" process, which includes validating what was entered and granting an authorization/access to proceed.

So, either thing *can* be said. "Completing login" is most correct for what the Stack Exchange page is in fact doing at that moment in time, however use of "log in" speaks more to the action the user had just performed, and so can be considered a friendlier (less technical) choice of wording.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/login) suggests `login` can also be a verb.

Answer (score 0):

You can logically make an argument for a couple of them being correct but "login to" should only be used when the login is being referred to as a noun because that is what it is.

-"Into" denotes motion and the action of going to 'log into' something is a motion from an unauthenticated state to an authenticated one.

- "In to" is an abbreviated form of "in order to" and almost always in the context of *doing* something. Since performing a login is an action that can be done, the argument in favor of "in to" checks out.
- "Login to" can really only be correctly used to refer to a credential login as a noun. IE "The 'login to' that account is in our credential manager" OR "Can you provide the temporary 'login to' my new account".